# Reemplazar por celdas vacías (Null) todos los textos(Object) de un DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy iniciandome en Python para tratar bases de datos númericas voluminosas.

Me gustaría que me pudiesen ayudar con un *código* que me permita Obtener el DataFrame2 (df2) a partir del DataFrame1 (df1), reemplazando `NotValue, Error` u otro texto object por celdas vacías `Null.

Esos textos pueden variar tanto en la posición en la que se encuentrar como el contenido del texto, por lo mismo es que me gustaría tener un **código que pueda reemplazar todo los textos Object por celdas vacías** `Null` independiente del texto Object. Acá un ejemplo simplificado:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,"NotValue","Error"], b=[3,"Error",8], c=[8,5,7]))
print(df1)

df2=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,"Null","Null"], b=[3,"Null",8], c=[8,5,7]))
print(df2)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Comment: Perdona, pero he leido varias veces tu pregunta y no logro entenderla ¿Qué quieres que te maque las celdas vacías como NaN?. Por otro lado tú código es incorrecto, el tipo de dato `Null` no existe en Python, existe `None`, al igual sucede con `NotValue` o `Error`. la *i* de `Import` va con minúscula. Por favor corrige tu pregunta y escriber la duda (o dudas) que tengas al respecto de forma más clara.

Comment: En un DataFrame me gustaría reemplazar todas las celdas que tenga un texto que no sea un número por un NaN, independiente del texto no numérico que tenga la celda (escribí como ejemplo "NotValue" o "Error", pero podría ser "Casa", "A", etc). Se que está la función "replace" para reemplazar valores definidos en las celdas por otro valor también definido, pero en mi caso me gustaría reemplazar todas las celdas del dataframe que tengan calquier texto no numérico por un NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente como comentas la forma más fácil es el método `replace()` te quedo tu ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,"NotValue","Error"], b=[3,"Error",8], c=[8,5,7]))

print(df1.replace("\D", np.nan, regex=True))
```

**Salida:**

```
     a    b  c
0  1.0  3.0  8
1  NaN  NaN  5
2  NaN  8.0  7
```

He hecho lo siguiente:

1. Me he importando la librería `Numpy` para tener el tipo de dato `NaN` con `np.nan`
2. Utilizo el método `.replace()` y pongo una expresión regular que indica que sustituya todos los campos que no sean númerosl, el caracter especial `\D` indica que sustituya **todos datos no números**. Después los sustituyo por `np.nan` y por último indico en el método que quiero que lo tome como una expresión regular.

Comment: Muy agradecido de la pronta respuesta Rubiales, funciona de maravilla el código con todas las bases de datos que he probado.

Comment: De nada siempre es un placer ayudar. Como eres nuevo posiblemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick "aceptar respuesta", y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recompensará a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia) :)